# how find newer works in unix

Tags: unix, find, sh, ksh

I have this set of similar lines which runs in my server.

```
PATH = "/home/dept/files/"

for i in '**find . -newer $PATH$(ls $PATH)**'

do
.. some set of codes.. done
```

I am not getting how the find newer command works here.
I saw that Find newer will return the files which are created after the specific time stamp. But I don't see any specific time stamp thats specified after the keyword **newer** in the find command. Please help me out how find -newer command works here.

Comment: The command does not look right. -newer is followed by a single argument and find will list the files which are newer than this file. I have no idea what the $(ls $PATH) is there for.

Comment: @surehw: you are right this command doesn't look right and its in the server. Thats why I am asking how this works else I would not have. But seeing the down votes may be I should figure out myself that this is a ignore able command. This is my first Question in the stackoverflow as well, felt bad to see down votes.

Comment: Clobbering your `PATH`, the single quotes around what should probably be a command substitution, and the syntax error in the assignment are obviously also problems. Voting to close as way too unclear; try http://shellckeck.net/ for diagnosing many basic beginner errors, and see also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for how to provide a [mre] to learn how to ask a well-defined question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The find -newer command will return files which are created after the specific time stamp. The time stamp here is the time stamp of the file defined by $PATH$(ls $PATH).**

If you wish to use this command to look for files modified in for example the last hour you can use the touch command to create a file with a timestamp that is one hour before now. So if it is 2pm now you would use the following command to create a file in the /tmp directory with a timestamp of 1pm:
`$  touch -mt 09301300 /tmp/file`

Then you would use the find -newer command to find all files that have been modified in the last hour:
`$  find / -newer /tmp/file -print`

Comment: Thanks for explaining -newer command. I have voted up. The above question will never have a answer, seems like its a wrongly written script. I will take your answers as accepted for giving explanation how proper newer command should be.